# The video after editing with ffmpeg in not showing in the phone gallery

Tags: java, android, performance, ffmpeg

I am working on a video editor app. The app works fine and edits the video. But the problem is the edited video is not showing in the phone gallery. I don't the problem. I also added the Media Scanner in the end but I didn't work out for me.

This is my video editor method

```
private void executeCutVideoCommand(int startMs, int endMs) {
        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
        );

        String filePrefix = "cut_video";
        String fileExtn = ".mp4";
        String yourRealPath = getPath(VideoCutterActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);
        File dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileExtn);
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dest.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dest = new File(moviesDir, filePrefix + fileNo + fileExtn);
        }

        filePath = dest.getAbsolutePath();
        String[] complexCommand = {"-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000,"-vcodec", "mpeg4", "-b:v", "2097152", "-b:a", "48000", "-ac", "2", "-ar", "22050", filePath};

        execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(VideoCutterActivity.this,
                new String[] { Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() },
                null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {

                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {

                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned " + path + ":");
                        Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> uri=" + uri);
                    }
                });

    }
```

**I just to show the edited video in phone gallery. I don't know what to do now. Help is much is appreciated**

Comment: I think you need to specify absolute paths to the exact file, not the directory.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Can you please explain it to me

Comment: Try supplying `filePath.toString` in place of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()`

Comment: Expect this everything is right?

Comment: Yeah, it works for me thanks

Answer (score 1):

> after complete your video editing you must call this method.

```
public void saveVideoToGallery(Activity activity, File videoFile) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("title", videoFile.getName());
    values.put("description", "video");
    values.put("_data", videoFile.getPath());
    values.put("mime_type", "video/mp4");
    values.put("datetaken", System.currentTimeMillis());
    values.put("bucket_id", videoFile.getPath().toLowerCase(Locale.US).hashCode());
    values.put("bucket_display_name", videoFile.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.US));
    values.put("_data", videoFile.getPath());
    ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
    cr.insert(android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a folder path, pass the path to the exact file.

Although it's called a `MediaScanner`, that apparently refers to scanning individual files, and not directories (like you might expect).

This is hinted at in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener)) for `static scanFile()`. Note than the function description seems to be linking to the wrong `scanFile()` prototype. Nevertheless, when you look at the description of `scanFile(String,String)`, it does mention that the first parameter is a path to a "file", and it doesn't mention directories, so we can infer that `static scanFile()` has the same requirement.